# A mapping from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to a dense subset of the surface of torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis

Define

$$\mathbf{f}(s,t) = \begin{pmatrix} (b+a\cos s)\cos t \\ (b+a\cos s)\sin t \\ a\sin s \end{pmatrix},\ 0 < a < b,\ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

as the mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $K$ be the range of $\mathbf{f}$.

Let $g(t) = \mathbf{f}(t,\lambda t)$ be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to $K$.

Take $\lambda$ irrational. Show that $g(t)$ is a one-to-one mapping onto a dense subset of $K$.

---

This problem comes from Baby Rudin (specifically, Chapter 9, problem 12). This is not a homework problem. (It is related to an exam problem from an exam I took almost a year ago).

---

For the exam, we only needed to show that $g$ was one-to-one. We did not need to show that it was dense in $K$. Showing one-to-oneness is pretty easy. Assume that it is not, then you get a condition where $\cos (t+\lambda 2\pi k) = \cos t$, which cannot hold for any irrational value of $\lambda$.

Is there a clever way to show density, or does it have to just be done directly from the definition?

Comment: Density follows almost immediately from [Kronecker's approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html). The theorem can be proved using elementary methods. The general idea of the proof is similar to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/197817/4583). Would you consider such an approach satisfactory?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes, indeed. I did not know that theorem, which is precisely what I was looking for. Perhaps later I should attempt the formal application to this problem.

Comment: I've added a formal proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(s_0, t_0)$ be a point on $K$. Consider $g(s_0 + 2\pi n)$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. By [Kronecker's approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html), and since $\lambda$ is irrational, we can choose an integer $m$ and a value for $n$ so that:

$$
\left|\frac{t_0 - \lambda s_0}{4\pi} - n \frac{\lambda}{2} + m\right| < \epsilon
$$

We have:

\begin{align}
\left|\sin t_0 - \sin \lambda(s_0 + 2\pi n)\right| &\le 2 \left|\sin\frac{t_0 - \lambda s_0 - 2\pi n \lambda}{2}\right| \\
&= 2 \left|\sin2\pi\left(\frac{t_0 - \lambda s_0}{4\pi} - n \frac{\lambda}{2} + m\right)\right| \\
&\le 4\pi\left|\frac{t_0 - \lambda s_0}{4\pi} - n \frac{\lambda}{2} + m\right| < 4\pi\epsilon
\end{align}

Similarly, we can show that for the same value of $n$:
$$
\left|\cos t_0 - \cos \lambda(s_0 + 2\pi n)\right| < 4\pi\epsilon
$$

It follows that $g(s_0 + 2\pi n)$ can get arbitrarily close to $f(s_0, t_0)$ as desired. Thus, the image of $g$ is a dense subset of $K$.