# Show that $\{e^{in}: n\in\Bbb N\}$ is Dense in the Unit Circle

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

This problem gave me fits when I was in grad school.  Looking back at it now, it still escapes me.  The problem is from Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable.  I'm looking for a proof from basic principles, so no big theorems please.

I remember that the Pigeonhole principle was involved, but I don't seem to be able to formulate it in the proper way.

Let $S$ be the unit cirlce, and $T=\{e^{in}:n\in\Bbb N\}$.  For a fixed $k$, $S$ can be paritioned into
$$A_{m,k}=\left\{e^{i\theta}:\frac{2\pi i(m-1)}{k}\le\theta\le\frac{2\pi im}{k},m=0,\dots k-1\right\}$$.
Now infinitely many members of $T$ must belong to $A_{m,k}$. Then $A_{m,k}$ can be partitioned in a similar manner, and in this way we can create a sequence of sets $S_n$ such that $S_{n+1}\subset S_n$ each of which contains infinitely many points of $T$.

So, $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$ is not empty, and since $\rm diam\, S_n\to 0$, then intersection is a singleton, which is a limit point of $T$. But this doesn't help, we already know $T$ has limit points in $S$ because it is infinite and $S$ is compact.

Comment: Try to use [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: I rember the Pigeonhole princple being involved, but I can't seem to make it work. I'll show my thoughts on that.

Comment: My impression is this at least has to use that pi is irrational, which is maybe a big theorem??  For example, e^(i * pi*n/20) is not dense in the unit circle.

Comment: @ CJD yes the irrationality is key.

Comment: @graydad Thanks that looks much better.

Comment: Does the equidistribution theorem count as a big theorem? I seem to recall that there's a proof relying on Fourier series, or something similar.

Comment: @JonathanY. Yes, that would be a big theorem.  The proof only requires basic principle of general topology.

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/449756/4583). The same technique can be used here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is identical to showing that the fractional parts of $\dfrac{n}{2\pi}$ are dense in $[0,1)$, which is true since $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$ is irrational (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/903142/1508)).

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to prove that $e^{in}$ is not periodic, in fact, that it never takes the same value twice. Given $\epsilon>0$, consider the partition of the circle into the $A_{m,k}$ arcs, with $k$ such that $\frac{2\pi}{k}<\epsilon$. Consider now the set of $k+1$ points $\{e^{in}: n = 0, 1, ... k\}$; at least one of the arcs contains two of the points in the set, say $e^{in_1}$ and $e^{in_2}$. Then, $d(e^{in_1}, e^{in_2})<\epsilon$, then, the metric being rotation invariant, $d(e^{i(n_2-n_1)}, 1)<\epsilon$. Let $r:=n_2-n_1$. Now, each two consecutive points of the form $e^{i r s}$, $s=0, 1, 2\; ...\;$, are $\epsilon$-close.