# Why can't this be a simple solution to Baby Rudin 9.12.d?

Tags: analysis, continuity

Fix two real numbers $a$ and $b$, $0<a<b$. Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ by

$$f_1(s,t) = (b+a \cos s) \cos t$$
$$f_2 (s,t) = (b+a \cos s ) \sin t$$
$$f_3(s,t) = a \sin s.$$

$f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ onto the torus, $K = f(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $\lambda$ be an irrational. Define $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow K$ by $g(t) = f(t, \lambda t )$.

Prove that the range of $g$ is a dense subset of $K$.

I know that this can proven using the Kronecker approximation theorem, as shown here [A mapping from $\mathbb{R}^1$ to a dense subset of the surface of torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449756/a-mapping-from-mathbbr1-to-a-dense-subset-of-the-surface-of-torus-in-mat?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

My question is can't we simply use continuous functions to prove this. Define $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $h(t) = (t, \lambda t)$. $h$ is continuous. We also know that $f$ is continuous, so any restriction of $f$ is continuous. Then $g(t) = f(h(t))$ is continuous.

Then, by problem 4.4 in Rudin, if $g$ is a continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ and $E$ is a dense subset of $X$, then $g(E)$ is dense in $g(X)$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and $g$ is continuous, then $g(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $K$.

Where is my mistake? Or is this valid?

EDIT: The mistake is in the last sentence as pointed out by Salcio in the comments.

Comment: it appears that  $g(R)$ is dense in its image ... which is $g(R)$ (not K)

Comment: @Salcio omg you are so right! Thanks